# jQuery insert multilevel HTML "smarter" way?

Tags: jquery

Periodically I need to insert multilevel HTML code dynamically with jQuery. I tend to just insert it this way:

```
$('#target').prepend('<div class="parent">' + 
    '<div class="child" data-id="' + someId + '">' + 
        '<h1>Some header</h1>' + 
        '<p class="info">' + someDynamicText + '</p>' + 
    '</div>' + 
    '<div class="sibling">' + someOtherInfo + '</div>' + 
'</div>');
```

Of course everything works, but I'm wondering is there a more fluid way to insert such an HTML block? Maybe jQuery has some kind of built in template system or something.. Dunno.. Just wondering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build up each element as a javascript variable rather than prepending one long string.

For example:

```
var $parent = $("<div/>");
$parent.addClass("parent");

var $child = $("<div/>");
$child.addClass("child");
$child.data("id", someId);

var $h1 = $("<h1/>");
$h1.text("Some header");
$child.append($h1);

//etc.....

$parent.append($child);

$("#target").prepend($parent);
```

Comment: This was my first thought too. Note you can make it a little more succinct by adding the attributes in the second argument of the element creator, like this: `var $child = $('<div/>', { 'class': 'child', 'id': someId });`

Comment: Thanks! I also thought if using this method, although it takes much more space, in the end it's more easier to add stuff to the parent than with appending static HTML blocks. Thanks!!

Comment: @Matt It takes up more line space, but this should never be considered a negative on its own. If its easier to read/manage, and doesn't hinder the performance much, then the more lines the merrier.

Answer (score 0):

there is number of jquery plugin that mange a design patterns such as [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com) for MVVM and so on... but for your case there is a simple and not complex library call [jQuery.tmpl](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl)

good luck!